# String cannot be converted to T java lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda

How can I resolve this error?
My code is:

```
  public Future<Set<Client>> getAllClients(){
    Future<Set<Client>> result = executorService.submit(() -> {
        Message request = new Message(HelloService.GETALL, "");
        Message response = tcpClient.sendAndReceive(request);
        String body =response.body();
        return body;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your expression is supposed to produce/return a `Set<Client>`. You cannot just return a `String`. Assuming that is even possible, you need to parse the String into a set of these objects.

Comment: Is your String composed of some parts, that can be decomposed, e.g. by using String delimiter? Therefore you could write Assembler to assembly `Set<Client>` using String.. Still, it's quite unnatural way of doing such this. You would be better of just returning `Set<Client>` from `tcpClient service`.